# In jquery mobile 1.3.1 how do you set selected value in a selectmenu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have tried numerous things.  Nothing seems to work.

for example:

```
$('#select').val(myval).selectmenu('refresh');
$('#select').val(myval).attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#select').val(myval).prop('selected',true);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$('#select').val(myval).selectmenu('refresh');
```

Just make sure `myval` actually matches a value in your options: `<option value="myval">My value</option>`

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-selects.html

Comment: var myselect = $("select#foo");
myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
myselect.selectmenu("refresh");

Comment: Dear Clinton, you are a genius. This saved me a lot of headaches. Thanks.

Comment: this works but does not trigger the onchange event for the selectmenu... ideas?