# JQuery Mobile select box not displaying selected option

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-mobile

I hope someone can help I've looked for the answer and tried many options…..  I have a HTML5 database and tables that is updated, then the select box is emptied, new select options are created. The problem is the selected option is not displayed. Below is the actual query Mobile code. Thanks

```
function updateCList() {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CourseTable', [], function (tx, results) {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            $('#coursemenu').empty();
            SelectOption(document.courseData_form.coursemenu, "Course Type", "Course Type")
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
                SelectOption(document.courseData_form.coursemenu, results.rows.item(i).c_type, results.rows.item(i).c_type);
            }
        }, null);
        $('#coursemenu').selectmenu('refresh', true);           
    });
}
```

Comment: You should probably show us the code for SelectOption()

Comment: SelectOption()  is the 6th and 8th line in the code. The list is created correctly the selected item (first by default) does not display.

Comment: @ezanker - Here is the html        <form id="courseData_form" method="post" name="courseData_form" class="form_padding">   
          <div class="displayList">
            <label for="coursemenu" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Course Name:</label>
            <select name="coursemenu" size="1" id="coursemenu">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Course Type</option>
            </select>
          </div> </form>

Comment: but what exactly does the SelectOption function do? I assume it creates and adds the select options, but show us the code.

Comment: Here is a fiddle that fakes a db call and fills in a select, just click the button below the select: https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/gwugcdqg/  Can you edit this to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my workaround. When I used the empty command the link to the default was broken, this code removes all option but the first.

```
            function emptyCList() {
                var select = document.getElementById("coursemenu");
                var len = select.options.length;
                for (i = len; i > 0; i--) {
                    select.options[i] = null;
                };
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

`executeSql()` is an asynchronous function, so when you call the `selectmenu('refresh', true)` to update the element, the options have still not yet been added. To avoid this, move the update command to the inside of the `executeSql()` function, like this:

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM CourseTable', [], function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length, i;
    $('#coursemenu').empty();
    SelectOption(document.courseData_form.coursemenu, "Course Type", "Course Type")
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        SelectOption(document.courseData_form.coursemenu, results.rows.item(i).c_type, results.rows.item(i).c_type);
    }
    $('#coursemenu').selectmenu('refresh', true);   
}, null);
```

Read more about the functions and syntax in the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/).

Comment: This did not work, either….. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16953680/in-jquery-mobile-1-3-1-how-do-you-set-selected-value-in-a-selectmenu/16953770#comment24486869_16953770